# Will like this btn on an onclick event to submit my form without altering onclick functions

Tags: jquery

here is the onclick event

```
  <li class="current">
  <a href="#" onclick="return false;">loading</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false;"><span class="vip"></span>

         <a href="#" class="loginBtn"
```

here is the form

```
 <form name="login" method="post" action="process.php">
```

How do i make the action submit when the btn has been clicked to submit form value to my external process.php?`

Comment: Sorry what are you trying to ask.

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes. Use `$(...).on('click', function () { /* do sometihng */ return false; });` instead.

Comment: What's the problem ..

Comment: please make question more clearer

Answer (score 0):

Add `id` attribute in form `id='login'`

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('#login').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a click handler for `loginBtn`

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.loginBtn').click(function(){
        $('form[name="login"]').get(0).submit();
        return false;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.loginBtn').on('click',function(){
  $('form[name="login"]').submit();
});
```